# AreQueryOptionsSupported and IsCommonFileQuerySupported always False

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to write an app that monitors a folder for pictures and refreshes when the photos in the folder changes. (If there is a better way to do this let me know.)

I am trying to use the CreateFileQueryWithOptions method of StorageFolders so I can limit the list of files to images and monitor changes.

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
StorageFolder photoFolder = await myPicsLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync();
// Set options for file type and sort order.
List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
//Todo : Do I need other file types?
fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);
```

The problem I am having is the following is ALWAYS false, even when I choose the Pictures folder.

```
photoFolder.AreQueryOptionsSupported(queryOptions)
```

Consequently, I cannot use the query to filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

As the document of [StorageFolder.AreQueryOptionsSupported(QueryOptions) Method Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.arequeryoptionssupported#remarks) part,

> The specific options available to you depend on where the files or folders that you want to enumerate are located. For folders and files that are located inside a library or homegroup, you can use any combination of QueryOptions.
>
> Folders and files outside of a library or homegroup support a only subset of options.
>
> **...**

You can see the above document to get the details.

Here is a simple example code from the document scenario 2 for queries that enumerate all of the files inside the current folder and its subfolders (also known as a deep query) and the `photoFolder` is outside of a library, you should specify the `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName` or `CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank`.

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
StorageFolder photoFolder = await myPicsLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync();
// Set options for file type and sort order.
List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, fileTypeFilter);

var result= photoFolder.AreQueryOptionsSupported(queryOptions);
```

Besides, for your initial aim of trying to write an app that monitors a folder for pictures and refreshes when the photos in the folder changes, I think the blog [Universal Windows Platform - File System Monitoring in Universal Windows Platform Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201.aspx) will help you much.

---**Update**---

As the [Add an existing folder to a library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries#add-an-existing-folder-to-a-library) topic,

> To add a folder to a library, you call the StorageLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync. Taking the Pictures Library as an example, calling this method causes a folder picker to be shown to the user with an Add this folder to Pictures button. If the user picks a folder then the folder remains in its original location on disk and it becomes an item in the StorageLibrary.Folders property (and in the built-in Photos app), but the folder does not appear as a child of the Pictures folder in File Explorer.

When you call the `RequestAddFolderAsync` method, it prompts the user to select a folder from a [picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#how-pickers-work), the app can not distinguish whether the picked folder is from a Library or not, even you pick the folder in a Library, the folder is still can not been recognized as a folder in the Library, so the **OrderByDate** is still not supported. You can try the following code to get and query the folder with a **OrderByDate** in the library .

```
var myPicsLibrary = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
var folders = myPicsLibrary.Folders;
List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);

foreach(var folder in folders)
{
    var result1 = folder.AreQueryOptionsSupported(queryOptions);
    var re1 = folder.IsCommonFileQuerySupported(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the Pictures folder a "Library"? As I said, even when I choose the actual Pictures folder it still fails.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott When the `RequestAddFolderAsync` method is called, it prompts the user to select a folder, and then adds the folder to the library. This folder's location decides whether is in the Library. In my test, If I used my above code, the result will be true whether the selected folder is in the library.

Comment: I tried a simple New UWP Project, add button and pasted in your code. I added the Photo Library Capability and your code "works" on the Photo Library. The problem is that I need OrderByDate. When I change your query the same library returns false.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I have added the **update** part in my reply, you can check it.